# JavaScript not working with putting innerhtml from databases

Tags: javascript, html

i have builded a java script code(here he is) :

```
function gup(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if (results == null)
        return "";
    else
        return results[1];
}
```

this code gets the permart from the head of the url and puts it into a span, now the problem is when i do "Something like that" its happend to get like that :

```
%22hey%20hey%22..
```

what can i do?

EDIT1:

I mean its takes parameters like that www.google.co.il?per="grg" and when i do www.google.co.il?per="Hey Hey" its like that %22hey%20hey%22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
return decodeURIComponent(results[1]);
```

You will get decoded string (Readable string in the sense)